# Best way to switch input source in Rust

Tags: pattern-matching, rust, lifetime, dispatch

I'm creating some ports based on arguments, but the ports don't live long enough to be passed to the next function, any lifetime-fu to be done? Better still, a way to adapt this to statically dispatch?

```
fn init<'a>(matches: getopts::Matches) {
    let in_port: &mut Read = match matches.opt_str("i") {
        Some(filename) =>  &mut File::open(filename).expect("Couldn't open input file.") as &mut Read,
        _ => &mut io::stdin() as &mut Read,
    };
    let out_port: &mut Write = match matches.opt_str("o") {
        Some(filename) => &mut File::create(filename).expect("Couln't open output file") as &mut Write,
        _ => &mut io::stdout() as &mut Write,
    };
    run(in_port, out_port);
}
```

Comment: Is the miscellaneous `'a` there intended?

Answer (score 1):

You can use static dispatch by calling the `run` function directly in every match arm:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Read, Write};

fn init(i: Option<&str>, o: Option<&str>) {
    match i {
        Some(filename) => init2(File::open(filename).expect("Couldn't open input file."), o),
        None => init2(std::io::stdin(), o),
    }
}

fn init2<R: Read>(i: R, o: Option<&str>) {
    match o {
        Some(filename) => run(i, File::create(filename).expect("Couldn't open output file")),
        None => run(i, std::io::stdout()),
    }
}

fn run<R: Read, W: Write>(i: R, o: W) {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully, bonus points for using static dispatch. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to `Box` your objects, putting them in the heap.

I would personally prefer to separate `init` and `run`, so it means returning them:

```
fn init(matches: Matches) -> (Box<Read>, Box<Write>) {
    let in_port: Box<Read> = match matches.opt_str("i") {
        Some(filename) =>  Box::new(File::open(filename).expect("Couldn't open input file.")),
        _ => Box::new(stdin()),
    };
    let out_port: Box<Write> = match matches.opt_str("o") {
        Some(filename) => Box::new(File::create(filename).expect("Couln't open output file")),
        _ => Box::new(stdout()),
    };
    (in_port, out_port)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to return a reference to something you're about to destroy:

```
let in_port: &mut Read = match matches.opt_str("i") {
    Some(filename) =>  &mut File::open(filename).expect("Couldn't open input file.") as &mut Read,
    _ => &mut io::stdin() as &mut Read,
};
```

Inside the block, the created `File` is a temporary which only lasts as long as the expression it's in.  I assume you're using references rather than values so that you can hide the concrete type behind a trait object.  One way would be to us `Box<Trait>`, which would own the object.

```
fn init<'a>(i: Option<&str>, o: Option<&str>) {
    let mut in_port: Box<Read> = match i {
        Some(filename) =>  Box::new(File::open(filename).expect("Couldn't open input file.")),
        _ => Box::new(io::stdin()),
    };
    let mut out_port: Box<Write> = match o {
        Some(filename) => Box::new(File::create(filename).expect("Couln't open output file")),
        _ => Box::new(io::stdout()),
    };
    run(&mut in_port, &mut out_port);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=23d6c18301c4858825bde58c94e17544&version=stable&backtrace=0))